# java giving error on https request

Tags: java, https, certificate

Here is my code

```
        URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

I am getting following exception

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching www.sandbox.freelancer.com found
```

As per I know this site does not have proper Certificate. But any how I have to login into this site. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
    new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
        public void checkClientTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
        public void checkServerTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
    }
};
```

Install the all-trusting trust manager

```
try {
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Now access an https URL

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://www.sandbox.freelancer.com");
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader br = 
         new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
}
```

Comment: Why not create a trust manager that just trusts that particular certificate and does default checking for all others?

Comment: @GregS yes, that could have been done, but I don't think that will solve the issue if a certificate has a chain of untrusted Root Certificate Authority.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the certificate (get it in firefox), and then add the certificate to the keystore, and then configure your app to use that keystore.

Comment: Can I get certificate directly from web without using firefox ?